# C#: Can't populate DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

Rather than use the designer I'm trying to populate a DataGridView I've put on my Winform programmatically. When I look in the table under the debugger it has the correct columns and number of rows. The problem is the grid appears as an empty grey box on my form. When I bind the grid to the database via VS 2008 Designer it worked fine. How can I track down the problem?

**UPDATE**

I pretty much took this from this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Do I have to do anything in the designer other than drop the grid on the Winform?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        private SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(Form1_Load);
            this.Text = "Cars";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
            GetData("select * from Cars");


        }

        private void GetData(string selectCommand)
        {
            string dbPath = "c:\\temp\\cars.db";

            try
            {

                var connectionString = "Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3";

                dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

                SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);


                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

                // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
                    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("To run this example, replace the value of the " +
                    "connectionString variable with a connection string that is " +
                    "valid for your system.");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to specify the DataMember property. And I think you don't require binding source object, directly you can bind DataTable to DataGridView control.

I am attaching a code which helps to bind gridview control with SQL Server database, and it works fine for me.

```
using(SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = 
    new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1",
        "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; Database=SampleDb"))
{
    using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
    {
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
}
```

Sorry I don't have SQLite installed :(

Comment: @vs dev: I tried setting DataMember to "Cars", but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Strange, I couldn't find any problem in the source code, instead of using BindingSource class, did you tried using Simple DataTable?

Comment: @vs dev Sorry, I'm new to this; could you perhaps add an example of the code I need to change/add in your answer please?

Comment: I added the GridView in the Designer.

Comment: @vs_dev - Thanks. I changed your code for sqlite, added it to Form1_Load and all worked.

Answer (score 2):

basically i dont think u should complicate this! here's an easy way:

```
        string cs = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=your db location;"; //connection string
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name"; //sql statment to display all data
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs); //connectiion
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn); //data adapter object
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //dataset object to keep data in table
        conn.Open(); //open connection
        da.Fill(ds, "table_name"); // fill the dataset with table_name through data adapter
        conn.Close(); //close connection
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; //populate the datagridview with dataset
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "table_name"; // populate datagridview with table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I have has difficulties with sqlite and also binding with linq. Now I have the same issue as above and ended up looping the data table to fill the grid.

I have noticed other minor issues with sqlite when using datatables and also databinding so I guess the problem lies with sqlite.

Here's some code to save time for anyone.

```
int rowcount = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)  
{
    dataGrid.Rows.Add();
    int column = 0;
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        dataGrid.Rows[rowcount].Cells[column].Value = item;
        column++;
    }
    rowcount++;
}
```