# After adding data source, how do I access it?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have added an access db data source to my c# project, and now I want to be able to access the data using C#.  If I right click the data source and press "Preview Data", I can see the data from the data source, but I don't know what code to use to access this data.

In the preview menu, it shows two methods .Fill, and GetData(), but I don't know how to access these.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't know the "Preview Menu" but Fill and GetData belong to the DataDapater. Now you have enough keywords to google a tutorial together.

Comment: what are you trying to bind the data to?  a datagriview or what control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking at the Fill/GetData methods that appear on the DataSet table adapters.  There are a lot of resources out there to example how to bind data including right here on SO I would suggest looking at some of the examples to see how to do it (the examples below are for `datagridviews`):

From [C#: Can't populate DataGridView programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486439/c-cant-populate-datagridview-programatically):

```
using(SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = 
    new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1",
        "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; Database=SampleDb"))
{
    using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
    {
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
}
```

[Dev X](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33748/1763/page/2) article in `VB` but it gives you the idea:

```
Dim connStr As String = _
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" & _
"Integrated Security=True"
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
'---open the connection and fill the dataset---
conn.Open()
'---fill the dataset---
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Customers_table")
'---close the connection---
conn.Close()
'---bind to the DataGridView control---
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
'---set the table in the dataset to display---
DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers_table"
```

From [MSDN Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    private Button reloadButton = new Button();
    private Button submitButton = new Button();

    [STAThreadAttribute()]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    // Initialize the form.
    public Form1()
    {
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        reloadButton.Text = "reload";
        submitButton.Text = "submit";
        reloadButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(reloadButton_Click);
        submitButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(submitButton_Click);

        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        panel.AutoSize = true;
        panel.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { reloadButton, submitButton });

        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { dataGridView1, panel });
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        this.Text = "DataGridView databinding and updating demo";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Bind the DataGridView to the BindingSource
        // and load the data from the database.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        GetData("select * from Customers");
    }

    private void reloadButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reload the data from the database.
        GetData(dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText);
    }

    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the database with the user's changes.
        dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);
    }

    private void GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
            // database accessible to your system.
            String connectionString =
                "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" +
                "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost";

            // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

            // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( 
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("To run this example, replace the value of the " +
                "connectionString variable with a connection string that is " +
                "valid for your system.");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and that it has an accepted answer but the answer doesn't seem to properly address the question.

As I see it the question is about data sources, data sets, and data tables created with the wizard because the question mentions preview data.  I had exactly this problem today.  I don't want to populate a control with the data I want to populate my own dictionary.

Here is my solution:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, InstrumentTransformer> InitInstrumentTransformers()
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, InstrumentTransformer>();

        using (var adapter = new _TSTAT_SETUPDataSetTableAdapters.SetupInstrumentTransformersTableAdapter())
        {
            var table = adapter.GetData();
            foreach (var row in table)
            {
                var instrumentTransformer = new InstrumentTransformer(row);
                result[instrumentTransformer.TransformerID] = instrumentTransformer;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

TSTAT_SETUP is the name of an Access mdb, SetupInstrumentTransformers is the name of a table in it.  TransformerID is the primary key.

The result is a dictionary of objects where each object was created from a row in the database.

The reason for doing it this way is that I already have the data source set up for showing other tables in datagridviews so it seemed silly to create new classes and objects to access it.