# data set in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

i am creating an application using visual studio that use a database of course. i don't get why we create a data set as i tried some query without creating a data set and it worked perfectly. the queries i will be using are update, delete, insert and select (simple and complex ones).

so should i use the data set and why?

Note the database is a big one, and as i understood creating a data set will create a copy of the database, so will this make a storage (memory) problem?

Comment: Do what works for you. DataSets facilitate data-binding so you can save a lot of boilerplate and error prone code if you databind. You haven't mentioned what platform you are using. Is it winforms? WebForms? WPF? UWP? Something else? There are a variety of ways you might work with data.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.. I can explain one thing for now.. a dataset will NOT involve copying a complete database. An *Adapter* or *DataSource* object that fills the dataset will only read the part of the database you are querying. For example, if your adapter Command is SELECT * FROM person, it will read the person table. Google *Query Plan* for more info, what happens depends on the database platform you are using. Tip: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587075/after-adding-data-source-how-do-i-access-it

Comment: honestly i still don't understand why i should use a dataset or adapter , what is the benefit for me .

Comment: let say i use this query  string connString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=info;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                string cmdText = "INSERT INTO customer( name) VALUES( '" + textBox1.Text + "')";


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = cmdText;

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: it worked well and the values are inserted directly to my database so why creating the temp table and not directly insert to db?thanks again

Comment: @Schwalbe for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE can use System.Data.Sql and System.Data.SqlClient, open your own SqlConnection and proceed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1  .... but for reads (SELECT), it is practical to use a DataSet. On this level (*below* Entity Framework !) the DataSet has a Fill() method, you can fill it with any data you want. The only class I know of that can read without a DataSet is DataReader, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: One reason not to do that (though it has nothing specific to do with DataSets) is SQL Injection. You should never concatenate strings to build SQL statements.

Comment: You are right, I included the issue in my answer. But appearently, this user is looking for a level that does not include DataSet or any other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for ways without a Dataset..

For INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE can use System.Data.Sql and System.Data.SqlClient, open your own SqlConnection and proceed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1  .... but for reads (SELECT), it is practical to use a DataSet. On this level (*below* Entity Framework !) the DataSet has a Fill() method, you can fill it with any data you want. The only class I know of that can read without a DataSet is DataReader, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

**NOTE**: as mensioned in the comments above, these low level methods to access a database are inherently unsafe, because you have to specify and pass explicit SQL to ADO, making user input vulnerable.. This can be avoided using a parametrized DataAdaper+Dataset, or Entity Framework, in either way you can avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big database you should consider using an ORM like Entity Framework. By using the old ADO .Net a dataset would help you handling your data. Inside it you will have a DataTable that represents your data and so, whenever you make a select the rows of your database will be stored temporarily in your dataset/datatable. That said, you don't need all your database there, but only the rows you need to work on. 
Every time you add a new record to the datatable, it is inserted flagged as new. When you modify a row, it is flagged as modified or deleted, when it is the case. So after all handling you can save your dataset back to the database.